# AS3 - set mcs to current label

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got 3 dolls : sitting, jumping, and running.
& I have dresses. All of my dresses models are designed in 3 positions : sitting, jumping & running.

- **dolls_btns** contains 3 btns to choose the doll, who starts with undies, their name are : sitting_with_undies, jumping_with_undies, running_with_undies.

  (Undies are removed when a dress is applied).
- **dolls_mc** contains : 
  on frame 1 : nothing
  on frame 2 : sitting_with_undies,           // label : sitting_with_undies
  on Frame 3 : sitting_naked,                 // label : sitting_naked
  on frame 4 : jumping_with_undies,           // label : jumping_with_undies
  on frame 5 : jumping_naked,                 // label : jumping_naked
  on frame 6 : running_with_undies,           // label : running_with_undies
  on frame 7:  running_naked                  // label : running_naked

  - **dresses_btns** contains buttons which allow to choose the color of the dress
  - **dresses_for_sitting** contains:
    on frame 1:  empty frame, 
    on frame 2:  1 pink dress    // label : pink_dress 
    on frame 3:  1 red dress     // label : red_dress 
    on frame 4 : 1 green dress   // label : green_dress 
    and more dresses
  - **dresses_for_jumping** contains:
    on frame 1:  empty frame, 
    on frame 2:  1 pink dress    // label : pink_dress 
    on frame 3:  1 red dress     // label : red_dress 
    on frame 4 : 1 green dress   // label : green_dress 
    and more dresses
  - **dresses_for_running** contains:
    on frame 1:  empty frame, 
    on frame 2:  1 pink dress    // label : pink_dress 
    on frame 3:  1 red dress     // label : red_dress 
    on frame 4 : 1 green dress   // label : green_dress 
    and more dresses

Lets say I choose the sitting doll & then apply her a pink dress. 
Next, if i click on  **dresses_btns.green_dress**, as the doll is already set to sitting,  the green sitting-shaped dress will come up. 
I can apply any other dress color, by clicking on my dresses_btns, as the position is set. // ok

But now if i click on running, the sitting-shaped dress doesn't disappear, as clicking on a doll only switches between dolls positions, but doesn't apply the correct shaped-dress.

So what i'm lookig for is : 
1) I choose the sitting position & 2) apply it a pink dress. // ok, done 
3) Then, when clicking on jumping >   I want to remove the sitting pink dress, & replace it by jumping pink dress .

---

As I have many dresses, many positions, many hair styles, & clothes, & accessories, I need an easy way to manage all of my items, according to the last clicked position.

```
// here we are in dolls_btns

var myDolls = [sitting_with_undies, jumping_with_undies, running_with_undies];

for each ( var doll in myDolls)
{
    doll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPositionClick);
    doll.buttonMode=true;
 }

function onPositionClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{ 
   MovieClip(parent).dolls_mc.gotoAndStop(e.target.name); // places the chosen doll's position on stage

if ( e.target == myDolls[2]  )  /// lets say I've clicked on running
     { 
         // what I'm trying to achieve : 
    if (  MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel=="pink_dress")
       {  MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.gotoAndStop(1) // empty frame
          MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_running.gotoAndStop("pink_dress");    
          // That works, but I'd like to use dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel instead of naming each label one by one, as I have too many cases, clothes, hair colors, & hair styles, accessories, etc
       }
   } 
}
```

I've been searching the web for over 12 hours & tryied many solutions, in vain.
I think currentLabel should do the trick but I lack of knowledge to complete my functions.

Anticipate thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (  MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel=="pink_dress")
       {  
          MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_running.gotoAndStop(dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel);  
          MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.gotoAndStop(1) // empty frame  
          // That works, but I'd like to use dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel instead of naming each label one by one, as I have too many cases, clothes, hair colors, & hair styles, accessories, etc
       }
```

Set *dresses_for_running* to the *dresses_for_sitting* current frame **before** setting
*dresses_for_sitting* to the first frame as I showed above.

Right now you are resetting it before assigning *dressing_for_running* to the *dresses_for_sitting* frame, so it resets as well

Comment: Thanks That's better indeed! <br /> But as I'm (not!) lazy, would u know how to replace "pink_dress" by only current label?
 
`var xx = dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel.name; // smthg like that
<br />

if (  MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel=="xx")
       {  
          MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_running.gotoAndStop(dresses_for_sitting.cxx);  
          MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.gotoAndStop(1) // empty frame  
          instead of naming each label one by one, as I have too many cases, clothes, hair colors, & hair styles, accessories, etc
       }`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks That's better indeed! <br /> But as I'm (not!) lazy, would u know how to replace "pink_dress" by only current label?
 
    var xx = dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel.name; // smthg like that
<br />

    if (  MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.currentLabel=="xx")
           {  
              MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_running.gotoAndStop(dresses_for_sitting.xx);  
               MovieClip(parent).dresses_for_sitting.gotoAndStop(1) // empty frame  
       
           }`

Thank u very much Naomi :)
// I'm trying to format my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I don't know why, my var xx = curentLabel works perfectly when I already tryied and it didn't work.... anyway.... 
OK, many thanks again